# How to realize a persistent queue on Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, queue

My application needs a data structure similar to a queue: put data in it, receive data from it, FIFO-like. With data I mean simple strings for now, later on perhaps more complex objects.
The thing is that the queue and its content should be persistent, regardless of what Android is doing. If the application gets closed and reopened (or even Android reboots), the queue should have the same state and data it had before the application was closed.

I think the queue has to use some kind of storage under the hood, preferably the internal storage of the device. Maybe you could do some brainstorming how to realize this. The queue doesn't necessarily have to run in my application, it could also be some kind of losely coupled background service if that is possible in Android (but private to my application).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend using a table inside `Sqlite`. I would create my own `SqliteQueue` that implements the Queue interface. `Offer` would add entry to the table.  `Poll` would return an entry and remove it from the table.  For more complicated objects you could use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert the object to a JSON string or convert the JSON string to an object.

Comment: I use this method for handling offline sync's of scanned barcodes in an app I recently wrote for work.  You can even create a serializable class to store multiple data chunks of various types in, and insert that into the database.  Since it's in the database, it's persistent, you just need to find it and pull it back out.

Another option is to store it as a serializable in a text file in the private storage directory for the app if you're basically just talking storing application state.  It's easier than db storage for a single batch of data for app state.

Comment: Oh what a coincidence. My intention is nearly the same - scan barcodes and similar things and keep them on the device for a while, for example if the device is in a no signal area where it cannot send data to a server. Do you think this also could work reliably with files in the internal storage or is the sqlite database a much better solution here?

Comment: Database. Then you don't have to write and re-write the file every time you have a change.  You dont have to worry about parsing the file.  Using the Sqlite helper classes isn't difficult either.

Answer (score 9):

May [squareup](http://square.github.io/tape/) is a good choice.

> QueueFile is a lightning-fast, transactional, file-based FIFO. Addition and removal from an instance is an O(1) operation and is atomic. Writes are synchronous; data will be written to disk before an operation returns. The underlying file is structured to survive process and even system crashes and if an I/O exception is thrown during a mutating change, the change is aborted.

Comment: The library is the *Tape* library for those that want to search for it.

Answer (score 3):

This is good library from Path:

https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue

"A Job Queue specifically written for Android to easily schedule jobs (tasks) that run in the background, improving UX and application stability."

And provide many features like priority, network check, callbacks etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty there are no such data structures in Java API, but there should be no problem in implementing your own kind of `Queue`. Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) document, which contains the description of Data Storage mechanisms in Android. I would suggest using `SharedPreferences`, but you may choose what fits your application most. You can extend one of the Java's collections which implements the `Queue` interface and add your persistence mechanisms using the Android's storage approaches. Hope this helps.

Comment: SharedPreferences are for primitive data types (i.e. int, double, String).

Comment: @Frohnzie, Every collection in Java has its String representation.