# How to implement a persistent queue in Android

Tags: java, android, message-queue, persistent-storage

I would like to implement a persistent queue in Android. Essentially a queue where data is stored until another thread takes it and sends it somewhere. The order in which data is stored or consumed is not important (ex. FIFO, LIFO, LILO, etc). Is there a modern library in Android that supports this?

I found a previous question on SOF but this dates from 2012: [How to realize a persistent queue on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033476/how-to-realize-a-persistent-queue-on-android)

Comment: why dont use     Stack lifo = new Stack() or Queue fifo = new PriorityQueue(); ?

Comment: Those look good, but how do I persist lets say the PriorityQueue after the Service/Activity is destroyed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of way to do this. You can persist the collection by saving it into a database like SQLite, serialize it as a file and deserialize it when you need it, or you can save it in SharedPreferences of Android.

Anyway there is a cool library called Hawk 
(https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk)
that is a

> Secure, simple key-value storage for android

How Hawk works:
[image: Hawk mechanism]

If you take a look at the Hawk source code you can see that it uses SharedPreferences to save data to the disk. It serializes the object you want to persist and saves it into SharedPreferences as a String.

Quotes and images are taken from Hawk github page.

You can find other alternatives here (in the "Persistence" section) : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Must-Have-Libraries

Comment: thanks for your thorough answer. I did not realize you can save a collection to SharedPreferences. I thought this was only for simple types. Is there a limit on the size of what you can store in SharedPreferences?

Comment: You cannot save collections directly into SharedPreferences. You can only save primitive types. But you can serialize the list (for example by converting the list into json) and save it as String. But you have to write the code to do this. So it is better to use a library like Hawk instead. In any case you need to serialize the object to store it. Anyway if the collection is very big it's better not to save it into SharedPreferences. That because SharedPreferences are saved as xml and can be slow to load a big xml. I think that the most efficient way is to use SQLite, but it's not the easiest.

Comment: Hawk uses SharedPreferences to save data to disk! So if you decide to save it in SharedPreferences I would definitely use Hawk ;)

Comment: thanks for the great explanation. One of the best responses I have ever gotten here!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Priority Jobqueue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue)

It has an option to persist the jobs and prioritise them.